# How to implement a daily streak counter in android java?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, counter, android-savedstate

I want to implement a daily streak counter for the user.
The streak count should increase by 1 if the user return t the app the next day, and the streak count should be again return to 1 if the user has not returned to the app the next consecutive day.

So far, i have tried implementing this using the given method in the image, but my daily streak always show 1.
I think this is because it is never going to the 'else' part.

Can you guys help me solve this thing.Any type of help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please share you code instead of screenshot, it's easier to look for error in code and also it's easy to copy in case of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what i wanted using this:

if(getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_TIME, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(STREAKS,0)==0){

}
else{

}

Answer (score 1):

savedInstanceState will return null on app launch you have to check first time user with like below.

```
     if preferences.getInt(STREAKS) == null{ 
    
    }else {}
```

Comment: thanks the actual answer hit me after reading your answer

Answer (score 1):

If the user logged in for the first time

- initialize last login date and reset streak

else

- if the user logged in on the same day
  do nothing
- if the user logged in consecutive days
  increase the streak and update the last login date
- if the last login date is more than a day
  reset the streak and last login date

Below is a pseudo implementation

```
class ConsecutiveDayChecker {

    /**
     * Call this method when user login
     */
    public void onUserLogin() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String today = dateFormat.format(date);
        String lastLoginDay = getLastLoginDate();

        String yesterday = getYesterdayDate(dateFormat, date);

        if (lastLoginDay == null) {
            // user logged in for the first time
            updateLastLoginDate(today);
            incrementDays();
        } else {
            if (lastLoginDay.equals(today)) {
                // User logged in the same day , do nothing
            } else if (lastLoginDay.equals(yesterday)) {
                // User logged in consecutive days , add 1
                updateLastLoginDate(today);
                incrementDays();
            } else {
                // It's been more than a day user logged in, reset the counter to 1
                updateLastLoginDate(today);
                resetDays();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getYesterdayDate(DateFormat simpleDateFormat, Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Update last login date into the storage
     * @param date
     */
    private void updateLastLoginDate(String date) {
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putString("last_login_day", date);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    /**
     * Get last login date 
     * @return
     */
    private String getLastLoginDate() {
        // String lastLogin = null;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // lastLogin = sharedPref.getString("last_login_day", null);
        // return lastLogin;
    }

    private int getConsecutiveDays() {
        // int days = 0;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // days = sharedPref.getInt("num_consecutive_days", 0);
        // return days;
    }

    private void incrementDays() {
        // int days = getConsecutiveDays() + 1;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putInt("num_consecutive_days", days);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    private void resetDays() {
        // int days = 1;
        // SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // editor.putInt("num_consecutive_days", days);
        // editor.apply();
    }

    public int getStreak() {
        return getConsecutiveDays();
    }
}
```